# Add vertical scroll in table row

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html-table, vertical-scrolling

What I need is to add vertical scroll for example if height is more than 200px. I tried with some solutions to wrap up `<tr>` in `<div>` tag and add overflow-y.. but no success. I also tried to add directly vertical scroll to table but I only need scroll in `<tr>` for checkboxes not for whole table. Below is my code and what I tried:

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="field_renderer.html">
  <table class="table table-scroll">
    <thead ng-show="data.name === 'Location'">
      <td class="noBorder" colspan="2">
        <button data-ng-click="reportsvm.changeLocation(data, true)" data-ng-class="" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
          Regions</button>
        <button data-ng-click="reportsvm.changeLocation(data, false)" data-ng-class="" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right">
          State/Territory</button>
      </td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-if="data.children.length > 0 && !$parent.$parent.$parent.data">
        <td class="noBorder" colspan="2">
          <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default-off btn-xs select-all" data-ng-click="reportsvm.selectAll(data)">Select All</a>
          <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default-off btn-xs reset-all" data-ng-click="reportsvm.clearAll(data)">Clear All</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat-start="data in data.children">
        <td class="noBorder">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{data.name}}" ng-change="reportsvm.changeValue(data, $parent.$parent.$parent)" ng-model="data.isSelected">
            <span class="clickable">{{data.name}}</span>
          </label>
        </td>
        <td class="noBorder clickable">
          <span ng-if="data.children.length > 0">
            <i data-ng-click="reportsvm.showChildDetails(data, $parent.$parent.$parent)" ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right': !data.showDetails, 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down': data.showDetails}"></i>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="data.showDetails">
        <td class="noBorder" ng-include="'field_renderer.html'"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>
<div class="panel-group">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div ng-repeat-start="data in reportsvm.modifiedFilters" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading clickable" data-ng-click="reportsvm.showDetails(data)">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a href="">{{data.name}}</a>
          <i ng-class="{'pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-plus': !data.showDetails, 'pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-minus': data.showDetails}"></i>
         </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body small" ng-if="data.showDetails" ng-repeat-end ng-include="'field_renderer.html'"></div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table-scroll {
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**RESULT**

[image: Result]

So I want scroll to be only after selectAll/Clear All buttons not whole body.

**DATA**

```
[{
  "name": "Location",
  "showRegions": true,
  "children": [{
    "isSelected": true,
    "name": "New Jersey",
    "category": "NERO"
  }, {
    "isSelected": true,
    "name": "Pennsylvania",
    "category": "MARO"
  }, {
    "isSelected": true,
    "name": "Connecticut",
    "category": "NERO"
  }, {
    "isSelected": true,
    "name": "Delaware",
    "category": "MARO"
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Review Status",
  "children": [{
    "isSelected": true,
    "name": "Planned",
    "children": []
  }, {
    "isSelected": true,
    "name": "Pre-Review",
    "children": []
  }, {
    "isSelected": true,
    "name": "Field Work Conducted",
    "children": []
  }]
}]
```

**PLUNKER**

https://plnkr.co/edit/CKZ9DeHee4pk7GUjVim2?p=preview

Comment: why do you have a table inside `<script>` tags?

Comment: Could you please add some static data . It would be helpful to debug.

Comment: @Anonymous I just added data.

Comment: @KevinKloet i had some problems to place data in rows without table so i needed this...

Comment: i understand that you need a table, but my question was: why is it in `<script>` tags?

Comment: Any link to view the prototype.

Comment: @Anonymous I can provide later plunker maybe for this thing, currently i am not able.

Comment: @KevinKloet well I am not sure if understand, you mean it is better to use table out of script tag, inside panel div?

Comment: `I want scroll to be only after selectAll/Clear All buttons.` have you tried changing your css to `.table-scroll > tbody {
}`

Comment: it doesn't seem very logical to put it in a `<script>` tag, although it works if you don't specify a non-html type in your script tag

Comment: @KevinKloet if I add this to <tbody> only difference will be that buttons wont be in scroll..

Comment: @Anonymous added plunker

Comment: adding a container element should work work to make the scrollbar appear after the select/clear all buttons .table-scroll > tbody > .tableContainer { }

Comment: @KevinKloet I am not so good with css can you show me snippet how you mean? in css this: .table-scroll > tbody > .tableContainer {
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
and then in html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping checkboxes in different rows , assigning `height` and `overflow` to it , may not work.

It would be great if you wrap all your checkbox in a container element and assign the same to it.

A simple codepen link I have created here.

[Link](http://codepen.io/swapnaranjitanayak/pen/ObgYYa)

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Table Header</td>
    <td>Table Header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="2">
     <div>
       Your all check box here
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia repellat voluptas, alias, culpa rerum voluptate cupiditate tenetur vitae maiores consequuntur tempora hic error, commodi soluta officiis eaque magnam doloremque illo.
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
div{
  max-width:200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Hm...Can you take a look at plunker? Cause i wrap up <tr> for checkboxes in <div> tag and it is not working... https://plnkr.co/edit/CKZ9DeHee4pk7GUjVim2?p=preview

Comment: Hi , I did this in a static way . Please use it as you need. Basically the structure would be tr > td > div > your checkbox

https://plnkr.co/edit/ayk3lklIbrqnE15Fzbe4?p=preview

Comment: Hm.. I updated my plunker  https://plnkr.co/edit/CKZ9DeHee4pk7GUjVim2?p=preview again like you did and wrong again... I am doing something wrong maybe..

Comment: You should not repeat your td . tr > td > div, they will remain fixed. Everything ex. your repetitive block will be inside of div wrapper. Hope help you.

Answer (score 1):

> I want scroll to be only after selectAll/Clear All buttons not whole body.

In that case, move the selectAll/Clear buttons to a `<thead>` row above the `<tbody>`:

```
   <table class="table">
        <thead ng-show="data.name === 'Location'">
            <td class="noBorder" colspan="2">
                <button data-ng-click="reportsvm.changeLocation(data, true)" data-ng-class="" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                    Regions</button>
                <button data-ng-click="reportsvm.changeLocation(data, false)" data-ng-class="" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right">
                    State/Territory</button>
            </td>
        </thead>
        <!-- Put selectAll/clearAll buttons here -->
        <thead ng-if="data.children.length > 0 && !$parent.$parent.$parent.data">
            <td class="noBorder" colspan="2">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default-off btn-xs select-all" data-ng-click="reportsvm.selectAll(data)">Select All</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default-off btn-xs reset-all" data-ng-click="reportsvm.clearAll(data)">Clear All</a>
            </td>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="table-scroll">
        <!-- Remove selectAll/clearAll buttons
        <tr ng-if="data.children.length > 0 && !$parent.$parent.$parent.data">
            <td class="noBorder" colspan="2">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default-off btn-xs select-all" data-ng-click="reportsvm.selectAll(data)">Select All</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default-off btn-xs reset-all" data-ng-click="reportsvm.clearAll(data)">Clear All</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        -->
        <tr ng-repeat-start="data in data.children">
            <td class="noBorder">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="{{data.name}}" ng-change="reportsvm.changeValue(data, $parent.$parent.$parent)" ng-model="data.isSelected">
                    <span class="clickable">{{data.name}}</span>
                </label>
            </td>
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/KQNLAIqcGgseIx83ae1D?p=preview).